# ¿Cómo obtener la cadena de conexión JDBC de una Base de Datos Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Para conectarse a una base de datos mediante [jdbc](/questions/tagged/jdbc) se necesita un *URL* (Localizador universal de Recursos) especialmente construido.
Tengo una base de datos `Oracle Express Edition` configurada localmente.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que la base de datos me genere el *URL* de conexión mediante una consulta?

Answer (score 4):

La BD como tal no te genera los connenction string, por demás está decir que es un trabajo que no requiere la BD para nada.

El formato para thin client es

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HOST>:<PORT>:<SID>
```

**driver name:** oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

También lo puedes mandar por OCI

**Oracle OCI 8i**

```
jdbc:oracle:oci8:@<SID>
```

**driver name:**oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

**Oracle OCI 9i**

```
jdbc:oracle:oci:@<SID>
```

**driver name:** oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

### USO

Para usarlos es sencillo, este es el ejemplo de conexión clásico

```
String connString="jdbc:oracle:thin:@prodHost:1521:ORCL";

OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL(connString);
ods.setUser("scott");
ods.setPassword("tiger");
Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
```

Y este es otro ejemplo clásico utilizando la sintaxis de TNS Names.ORA

```
String connString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=
   (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=prodHost)))
(connect_data=(INSTANCE_NAME=ORCL)))";
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();

ods.setURL(connString);
ods.setUser("scott");
ods.setPassword("tiger");
Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
```

Acá tienes full documentación

#### [JDBC + Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#OCI_driver)

Answer (score 0):

hasta donde conozco no es posible generar la cadena de conexión desde la misma base de datos, sin embargo es muy sencilla de crear, además existen multitudes de ejemplos en internet:

```
SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;
```

puede reemplazar con 'XE', si estás usando la versión XE de oracle.